# How do I safely perform the below changes to network parameters on Solaris 10?

Tags: networking, solaris, administration, tcp-ip

I need to change and test some TCP/IP network parameters on a Oracle Solaris 10 as a possible workaround for a bug in 'Oracle Hyperion EPM 11.2.1.0' in the development environment.
I am not a Solaris/UNIX expert so would appreciate any guidance to identify the correct parameters and also it would be very helpful if you could tell me the possible impact of the changes and how I could have the admin support rollback the changes.

1. I need to decrease the time wait before closing the sockets. I already have the corresponding UNIX command: 
   `$ echo 3 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout`
2. I need to check if the System is preventing the 'Oracle Hyperion EPM' application from using a large number of sockets. How do I check the port range and modify it? The UNIX command for it would be: `$ echo "1025 65535" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`

I am advised that I need to make these changes as root and execute the following UNIX command for applying the changes: `$ /etc/rc.d/init.d/network restart`

**References:**

1. I looked at the parameters in `$ ndd /dev/tcp \?`
2. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2724/6n50b07lr/index.html
3. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101138&seqNum=6

Comment: For #1, will tcp_time_wait_interval be the correct Solaris parameter? Are there any good references for this as `$ man ndd` is not that helpful?

Comment: `tcp_fin_wait` is for connections that don't close properly (lost ack). `tcp_time_wait` is for normal closed connections (to hold a slot open to soak up stray packets), usually the first thing to tune on a busy server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one:

```
ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_time_wait_interval 90000
```

as per the oficial manualyou should not set this under 60000 = 60 seconds.

For the second one

```
ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_smallest_anon_port tcp_largest_anon_port
```

No need to restart the network. But if you feel like it, in solaris 10 is

```
svcadm restart network/physical
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandre! Is there any available documentation I could read to better understand this..?

Comment: usually these parameters are changed due to the application that is being installed. I can't find at the moment a list with them as I found this in my notes. I'll search and if I find I'll put the link here with the explanation of every var there.

Comment: Found it :) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-0404/chapter4-31.html List of all the parameters and explanation.